# No Alt+F2 in Ubuntu Netbook 10.10?

Tags: 10.10, shortcut-keys, ubuntu-netbook, unity

I am stumped. I upgraded from 10.04 to 10.10 Beta 3 and for some reason I can't get Alt-F2 to do anything. Is this a known bug or am I just not doing the right thing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a known limitation of the new Unity shell. The bug to track is here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/580295

Answer (score 3):

It is a known bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk+2.0/+bug/398826

Comment: See this discussion here for some more information: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1209519&page=3

Comment: Thanks. Except you can't switch off transparency on the new remix. Frustrating.

Comment: That bug is for the gnome-panel, which isn't in the netbook edition, seperate bug.

Answer (score 3):

As a workaround you could install gnome-do.

apt://gnome-do

If you run this program, you can press Meta+Space, and then type in a command.
This will accept the same commands as the ALT+F2 dialog, and more.

Answer (score 0):

Like the others said, Alt-F2 is gone in netbook-edition 10.10 because of the switch to Unity.  And as other suggested, gnome-do is a good replacement.

However, there is one more important step to make it work.  The default keyboard shortcut for the Gnome-do menu, Super + Spacebar (aka Win key + space), won't work because Unity grabs use of the Super key.  SO, after installing gnome-do you'll need to modify this.  You can do this by running gnome-do from a terminal and using the drop down preference menu to modify the shortcut.  I like Ctl Alt Space.

Answer (score -3):

There shouldn't need to be a workround if this is going to be used as a default. More forward thinking from Canonical it seems is needed.